# var属性に指定したコンポーネントをコントローラーで使用できない

Tags: onsen-ui

下記のようにvar属性にcarouselコンポーネントを指定しております。

```
<ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen var="app.carousel" ng-controller="FooController">
```

次にコントローラーでcarouselをログに出力しました所、undefinedが返って来てしまいます。
こちらのコードの問題点わかりましたらご教示頂ければと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
(function(){
'use strict';

app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log(app.carousel);
}]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コンポーネントにアクセスするにはOnsenUIの初期化完了を待つ必要がありますので、`ons.ready()`関数を利用してください。

```
(function(){
'use strict';

app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    ons.ready(function(){
        console.log(app.carousel);
    });
}]);
})();
```

参考
http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingVarAttributeToSpecifyAComponent